# Testing a type for (Eq a) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm trying to see if I can implement something which branches on whether the type implements Eq.

Here's an attempt:

```
data HTrue
data HFalse

type family Eq1 (a :: *) where
  Eq1 (Eq x) = HTrue
  Eq1 a = HFalse
```

You'll note that I put (a :: *) in the code. That's because if I don't, the code compiles, but generates Eq1 as a constraint, while I actually want it to be a closed type family.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: What would be the application of this?

Comment: Consider 

    testEqual :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Typeable b, Eq b) => a -> b -> Bool
    testEqual x y = fromMaybe False $ (== x) <$> cast y

...which works but requires Typeable.

You could also do stuff like "Sort the list IF a is Ord"

Comment: Open type classes (like `Eq`) and separate compilation cope with this type family. E.g. what if module `A` defines a type `T`, and `f :: Eq1 T -> HFalse ; f x = x`, and then module `B` imports `A` and adds `instance (Eq T)`? When should the type error be detected?

Comment: As chi has stated, this won't work, and it necessarily shouldn't work. Your choices are to abandon this line of thinking or write your own `Eq` as `class Eq a (b :: Bool) | a -> b; instance Eq Int True; instance Eq Bool True; instance Eq SomeType False; ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of instances, visible in different contexts, is also different, so any such function would be very dangerous. Seriously, don't do that. Consider defining two newtypes like this:

```
module EqTest (HasEq, NoEq, hasEq, noEq, fromEq)
newtype HasEq a = HasEq a
newtype NoEq a = NoEq a
hasEq :: Eq a => a -> HasEq a
hasEq = HasEq
noEq :: a -> NoEq a
noEq = NoEq
class FromEq c where fromEq :: c a -> a
instance FromEq HasEq where fromEq (HasEq a) = a
instance FromEq NoEq where fromEq (NoEq a) = a
```

and do not export constructors. You would have to always specify which version you'd like to use, but that's better than relying on class instances.